# I need to find the mechanism of a reaction

Tags: reaction-mechanism

As in the title, I have a reaction to witch I need to give the mechanism.[image]

Comment: Get out your textbook. Shouldn't be hard to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
The image shows the complete mechanism

Comment: It would be better if you provide some explanation.